# Two figures simultaneously in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, figure

I have a code that runnes two figures either alone or simultaneously. The problem is when they are running simultaneously. Both of them are not showen correctly. I tried to use `plt.subplotlib` but it didn't help. 
here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Choice = input('Which figure do you want to run: \n *for Fig.1 , write 1 \n *for Fig.2, write 2 \n *for both , write b \n--> ')  
Etta_Source={};Etta_Source1={};QKN_Source={}

for E_So in [100,200,400,800,600,1000]:
    for Temp in range(0,110,10):
        Etta = 0.8 - ((3.41*Temp)+(0.014*(Temp)**2))/E_So
        if Choice == '1' or Choice == 'b':
            QKN_Source[Temp] = Etta*2.3*E_So
        Etta_Source[Temp] = Etta
        if E_So == 1000 and (Choice == '2' or Choice == 'b'):
            Etta_Source1[Temp]=Etta
    if Choice == '1' or Choice == 'b':
        plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(QKN_Source.keys(),QKN_Source.values(),label='D = %s'%E_So)
        QKN_Source.clear()
    if Choice == '2' or Choice == 'b':
        plt.figure(2)
        plt.plot(Etta_Source.keys(),Etta_Source.values(),label='C= %s'%E_So)
        Etta_Source.clear()

if Choice == '2' or Choice == 'b':
    plt.axhline(0.8,ls='-.',color='skyblue')
    plt.fill_between(Etta_Source1.keys(),Etta_Source1.values(),0.8,facecolor='wheat') 
    plt.axhspan(0.8,1.0,alpha=0.5, color='c')
    plt.axis([0,100,0,1])
    plt.text(50, 0.9, r'Area 1',fontsize=14,fontweight='bold')
    plt.text(80, 0.6, r'Area 2',fontsize=14,fontweight='bold')
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.1))
    plt.ylabel('W',fontsize=14)
if Choice == '1' or Choice == 'b':
    plt.axis([0,100,0,2000]) 
    plt.ylabel('V',fontsize=14)

plt.grid(True)   
plt.title('Results',color='black',fontsize=15,fontweight='bold')
plt.xticks(range(0,110,10),fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel(r'$\beta_a +  \alpha_a$',fontsize=14)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend(loc=1)
plt.show()
```

Wrong figures: 
[image]

the figures should look like this when they are both running
[image]

Comment: just type b when the question appears and then two figures will be showen

Comment: I guess you need to type 'b' and not b to make it work

Comment: just the letter b

Comment: `plt.axis([0,100,0,2000])` applies the scaling to the second figure, since you don't specify the axes. Another sign of this effect is that the y-axis label "V" is now in the second figure, because this command is executed after the generation of the first figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't specify the [axis object](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py), so therefore `plt.XYZ` just takes the last object to perform the function. A way to overcome this problem is to store each axis object in a variable so you can address them separately. Here is an example as close as possible to your code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Choice = input('Which figure do you want to run: \n *for Fig.1 , write 1 \n *for Fig.2, write 2 \n *for both , write b \n--> ')  
Etta_Source={};Etta_Source1={};QKN_Source={}

for E_So in [100,200,400,800,600,1000]:
    for Temp in range(0,110,10):
        Etta = 0.8 - ((3.41*Temp)+(0.014*(Temp)**2))/E_So
        if Choice == '1' or Choice == 'b':
            QKN_Source[Temp] = Etta*2.3*E_So
        Etta_Source[Temp] = Etta
        if E_So == 1000 and (Choice == '2' or Choice == 'b'):
            Etta_Source1[Temp]=Etta
    if Choice == '1' or Choice == 'b':
        fig1 = plt.figure(1)
        #get axis object for this figure
        ax1 = plt.gca()
        #now perform all commands with this axis object 
        ax1.plot(QKN_Source.keys(),QKN_Source.values(),label='D = %s'%E_So)
        QKN_Source.clear()
    if Choice == '2' or Choice == 'b':
        fig2 = plt.figure(2)
        #and create a separate axis object for the second figure
        ax2 = plt.gca()
        ax2.plot(Etta_Source.keys(),Etta_Source.values(),label='C= %s'%E_So)
        Etta_Source.clear()

axlist = [] #collect the axes for the choices
if Choice == '2' or Choice == 'b':
    ax2.axhline(0.8,ls='-.',color='skyblue')
    ax2.fill_between(Etta_Source1.keys(),Etta_Source1.values(),0.8,facecolor='wheat') 
    ax2.axhspan(0.8,1.0,alpha=0.5, color='c')
    ax2.axis([0,100,0,1])
    ax2.text(50, 0.9, r'Area 1',fontsize=14,fontweight='bold')
    ax2.text(80, 0.6, r'Area 2',fontsize=14,fontweight='bold')
    ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.1))
    ax2.set_ylabel('W',fontsize=14)
    axlist.append(ax2)
if Choice == '1' or Choice == 'b':
    ax1.axis([0,100,0,2000]) 
    ax1.set_ylabel('V',fontsize=14)
    axlist.append(ax1)

#now we have to apply these commands to both axis objects, i.e., both figures
for ax in axlist:
    ax.grid(True) 
    ax.set_title('Results',color='black',fontsize=15,fontweight='bold')
    ax.set_xticks(range(0,110,10))
    ax.set_xlabel(r'$\beta_a +  \alpha_a$',fontsize=14)
    ax.legend(loc=1)
plt.show()
```

And since you mentioned that you tried to use subplots - [they return an axis object](http://www.math.buffalo.edu/~badzioch/MTH337/PT/PT-matplotlib_subplots/PT-matplotlib_subplots.html#axes-objects), which we can store and re-use later.

Comment: Not quite. I have edited now the code to take into account that maybe only one figure is chosen. And please read the linked documentation, it is not difficult to utilize this concept.

Comment: your editing doesn't work for one figure but i fixed it.

Comment: Strange. I was pretty sure to have corrected it. Oh, well. All good now.